# Microsoft Outlook python new line character

Tags: html, python-3.x, office365, html-email

I am trying to figure out how to send some output from a python script to my outlook mailbox. Now I'm having some issues with formatting. My original method is below

```
def email_mailbox(file_checked, error_list):
    error_msg = ''
    for e in error_list:
        if e is not None:
            e += '\n'
            error_msg += e
    if len(error_msg) > 1:
        error_msg += '\nAutomated Test Result: FAILED'
    else:
        error_msg = 'Automated Test Result: PASSED'
    msg = MIMEText(error_msg)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Automated Review ' + file_checked[:-6]
    msg['From'] = 'a'
    msg['To'] = 'b'
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smlsmtp')
    s.sendmail('a', 'b', msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
    print(file_checked + ' Review Email Sent')
```

The problem with this is that for some unknown reason to me when I send large amounts of output, some lines are not displayed on a new line

[image]

Using Note Pad to open the email address i can see that the formatting looks ok

```
UBNZI91D Does not start with a P<BR> 
UBNZI09M Does not start with a P<BR> 
UBNZC66D Does not start with a P<BR>
UBNZC66D Quantitative Resources not correct<BR> 
UBNZC67D Does not start with a P<BR> 
UBNZC67D Quantitative Resources not correct<BR> 
UBNZC68D Does not start with a P<BR> 
UBNZC68D Quantitative Resources not correct<BR> 
UBNZC69D Does not start with a P<BR> 
UBNZC69D Quantitative Resources not correct<BR> 
UBNZF08D Does not start with a P<BR> UBNZEND1 Does not start with a P<BR>
```

My python skills are ok and im pretty sure this is an encoding problem but I for the life of me cant figure why its not formatting correctly. I have tried

```
for e in error_list:
    if e is not None:
        new_line = '<BR>'
        new_line.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
        e += new_line
        error_msg += e
```

which I found here http://beckism.com/2009/03/named_entities_python/ with no luck. Reading the plain text of a normal text email I sent in outlook, I find the following

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 14.03.0162.000">
<TITLE>test 2</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/plain format -->

<P><FONT SIZE=2>New line<BR>
New line<BR>
<BR>
Cheers,<BR>
<BR>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in this mystery

Answer (score 0):

Consider automating Outlook from your preferred programming language instead. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](http://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/201096) and [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9). The [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN describes all possible ways of working with message bodies.

Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the reply eugene. WIll look into it as soon as I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

Definitely late for this answer, but someone might end up here as I did.
Using the win32com library to automate Outlook I ended up setting the body format to 2 and use HTMLBody for the message. Of course keep the answer regarding automating MS products in mind.

```
import win32com.client as win32
olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
mailItem.Subject = 'Subject'
mailItem.BodyFormat = 2
mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html>Some text<br>New line</html>"
mailItem.To = 'myself@example.com'
mailItem.Send()
```